# App Scripts If Statement always returning Else Condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a script to perform an Index/Match task on two seperate workbooks. The code seems to be working but my If statement is always returning its Else condition. I have logged the compared vairables `find` and `searchref` and found that they do match at some point durring the loop but the If statement still returns its Else condition.

I suspect this has something to do with how I am comparing these arrays but I have not been able to figure it out.

Here is a snip of the first few columns and rows for the source spreadsheet for `searchData` I am trying to access the information in column B.

[Source data for searchData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZulP.png)

Here is the output from `Logger.log` for `findData` and `searchData`

[Logger with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG4cv.png)

[Logger arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFKDO.png)

[Source data for findData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll1EM.png)

```
function generateBillOfMaterials() {
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Declare variables
  var i, j
  var find
  var searchref
  var found = []
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------

  var search_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Searched-Spreadsheet-ID");  
  var find_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xg2yVimBwE5rGvSFMtID9O9CB7RauID34wqIH5LLTeE");

  var ssheet = search_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("METAL PARTS");
  var fsheet = find_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Bill of Materials");
  var FMaxR = fsheet.getMaxRows();

  fsheet.getRange(2, 3, FMaxR, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});

  var findData = fsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var searchData = ssheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < findData.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {

      find = findData[i][1];
      //Logger.log(find)
      searchref = searchData[j][0];
      //Logger.log(searchref)
      if (find == searchref && find != "") 
      {
        found[i] = searchData[j][1]
      }
      else 
      {
        found[i] = ['n/a']
      }
      //        found = ssheet.getRange(j+1,2,1,1).getDisplayValue();
      //        fsheet.getRange(i+1,16,1,1).setValue(found);
    }

  }
Logger.log(found)
  fsheet.getRange(2, 3, found.length, 1).setValues(found)
}
```

Comment: It may be hard to provide help, without knowing how the input data is structured. For example, `searchData[j][1]` may or may not return anything, depending on the positioning of data in the source spreadsheets - for example, if the data is in column B in each case, you will always get "n/a".

Comment: It may be easier if you first flatten your arrays `findData.flat()` and `searchData.flat()` before processing them (if they are not already flat).

Comment: I am trying to access the information from Column B in the source spreadsheet for `searchData` I have added a snip of the first few rows and columns to the origional post. 

I tried running `findData.flat()` and `searchData.flat()` on my arrays before running the for loop and it has not seemed to change the arrays or the output.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Which sheet is the "source" spreadsheet? Is it the "METAL PARTS" sheet, or the other one? Can you provide a similar screenshot of the "other" sheet also, since your logic involves array handling in both sheets (so the data layout may be important in that other sheet, also).

Comment: Yes, the source spreadsheet for the searchData is "METAL PARTS" the "source" for the findData is the "Bill of Materials" 

I have included another snip of the other sheet in the origional question. This has all of the "n/a" that gets placed after running the script.

I also ran the logger on `searchData[j][1]` as it went through the loop and found that it is pulling the correct information for revision. The If statement still does not recognize when `find == searchref`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in the sample code is the `else` statement containing this:

```
found[i] = ['n/a']
```

This will overwrite whatever is found earlier in the loop, because even after a match has been found (and assigned to the `found` array), the loop continues comparing the remaining values in the inner loop.

The following approach shows how to correct this, making as few changes as possible to your existing code:

```js
function generateBillOfMaterials() {
  //  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Declare variables
  var i, j
  var find
  var searchref
  //  --------------------------------------------------------------------

  var search_spreadsheet = ... ; 
  var find_spreadsheet = ... ;
  var ssheet = search_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("METAL PARTS");
  var fsheet = find_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Bill of Materials");
  var FMaxR = fsheet.getMaxRows();
  fsheet.getRange(2, 3, FMaxR, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});

  var findData = fsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var found = new Array(findData.length).fill('n/a'); 
  var searchData = ssheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < findData.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {

      find = findData[i][1];
      searchref = searchData[j][0];
      if (find === searchref && find !== "") {
        found[i] = searchData[j][1];
        break; 
      }
    }

  }

  const found2 = found.slice(1).map(x => [x]);
  fsheet.getRange(2, 3, found.length-1, 1).setValues(found2);
}
```

Notes:

We pre-fill the array of "found" values with "n/a":

```
var found = new Array(findData.length).fill('n/a');
```

This allows us to overwrite "n/a" when we find a value - otherwise we leave the "n/a" untouched.

When a match is found, we break out of the inner loop using `break`.

Then we can remove the `else` condition - as we no longer need it.

The remaining changes are to ensure the final shape of the `found` data is a two-dimensional array which can be written to the spreadsheet.

---

The above approach involves repeatedly looping over the data in the inner loop.

In reality, we only need to visit each list once, in order to perform the lookups we need.

Implementing this alternative approach would basically be a rewrite of what you have - and I would imagine that what you have, even if it is somewhat inefficient, is perfectly OK for your needs. But I did want to mention this.

---

The other note which may be of interest is that my alternative approach is more-or-less the equivalent of using a Google Sheets `vlookup` formula. Apologies if you are already aware of that. And I have never tried using that formula across 2 separate files, anyway. But again, just wanted to mention it, for completeness.

---

**Update 2**

*"Is there a lookup command that could be used in place of the for loops?"*

It's more a question of avoiding the *nested* loops, and using a JavaScript data structure that supports lookups (a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)).

Here is a sketch:

```js
// assume we have already populated searchData and findData, as usual.

// first iterate searchData to build a lookup map:
let partsLookup = new Map();
for (i = 1; i < searchData.length; i++) {
  partsLookup.set( searchData[i][0], searchData[i][1] );
}

// now iterate the BOM data and use the lookup map:
for (i = 1; i < findData.length; i++) {
  var foundValue = partsLookup.get( findData[i][1] );
  console.log( foundValue ); // add this to the "found" array
}
```

This is obviously not "finished" code - it just shows the approach. But no nested iterations are needed.

The number of loops performed is `searchData.length + findData.length`, instead of up to `searchData.length * findData.length`

Comment: Thank you! This is working now. 

I am aware that this is pretty much a `vlookup` but from what I can tell the`vlookup` does not work across two different workbooks.

I will use this as is for a little while and see how it works. If I find I need more speed I will look into your suggestion. Is there a lookup command that could be used in place of the `for` loops? I am pretty new to creating these scripts so I am sure there is a lot of functionality I am not aware of. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I will have to look into using a `Map` if this gets to be too slow.

What if I wanted to grab columns 2-5 from the `searchData` source spreadsheet instead of just the single column?

Comment: Give it a try - and that can be a new question, if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I was able to get this script to do everything I wanted and I learned something in the process. Its a little slow but it is working for the time being.